# Счетчик времени Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Как реализовать счетчик, который выдает время, проведенное в приложении? 
Так же интересует, как можно учитывать количество нажатий на иконку приложения, то есть вхождений в него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто. Есть метод под названием `onCreate`, он отслеживает старт приложения или активности и выполняет указанные в нем действия. Для того, чтобы сохранить данные о времени, проведенном в приложении и о количестве его запусков, надо просто создать два тестовых файла: в первый загружать количество запусков приложения, а во второй - время, проведенное в нем. С первым файлом все просто, а для второго надо создать отдельный поток, чтобы не загружать основной, и уже из него загружать в файл данные о времени, к примеру, ежеминутно.

Почитать подробнее можно здесь:

- [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ru#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))
- [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer)